# cast SKSpriteNode to UIImage

Tags: swift, uiimage, skspritenode

I want to convert a SKSpriteNode into an UIImage.

```
let testImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "PlainProject") as! UIImage
```

but I get a crash on the thread above.  Is there another way to do this?

Comment: please check the answers and reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the `cgImage` of the `texture` of the sprite first, and then cast it to `UIImage`:

```
let testImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "someImage.png")
let image = UIImage(cgImage: (testImage.texture?.cgImage())!)
```

or a better version without force-unwraping a `cgImage` that might be `nil`:

```
let image = UIImage()
if testImage.texture?.cgImage() != nil{
    image = UIImage(cgImage: (testImage.texture?.cgImage())!)
}
```

**Result (in playground):**

[image]

That is exactly what my image looks like. Hope this helps!

Comment: That works really well thanks.  I found working with the texture meant I needed some extra work on the image scale but it's all good now.

Comment: You're welcome. If you have any further question, please ask

Answer (score 2):

You can not directly do that.

First of all you need to get `texture` from `SKSpriteNode`.

After that you can get image with `textureOfNode!.cgImage()` as shown in below example:

```
let testNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spaceship")
let textureOfNode = testNode.texture
let imageFromTexture = UIImage.init(cgImage: textureOfNode!.cgImage())
print(imageFromTexture) //<UIImage: 0x61000008afa0>, {394, 347}
```

Comment: also a nice answer! Thanks

Comment: Happy to help you.. :)